# Closure-like function without declaration and intialization (i.e. without `auto f = make_closure();`)

Tags: c++, lambda, closures

A typical example of closure in c++ is like below:

[code1]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<void()> make_closure(){
    int i = 0;
    return [=]() mutable -> void{i++; std::cout << i << std::endl;};
}

int main(){
    auto f = make_closure();
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) f();
}
```

This will display 1, 2, .... 10 in the command line. Now, I am curious about how to make a closure-like function without declaration and initialization, more precisely function `f` like below:

[code2]

```
#include <iostream>

void f(){
//some code ... how can I write such a code here?
}

int main(){
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) f();
}
```

where `f` in this code works exactly the same as in the [code1]. The difference between [code1] and [code2] is that, in [code2]  we don't have to declare and initialize `f` by `auto f = make_closure();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really identical, but you will got same output with:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>

void f(){
    static int i = 0;
    i++;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) f();
}
```